# Authentication issues on Colab/Bigquery

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I use BigQuery from Colab for a long time, and since 2020 my account is on Google's enhanced security program. Until yesterday I had no issues authenticating with

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Now, though, I get a 400 error. These are the details it gives:

```
access_type: offline
login_hint: (email)
response_type: none gsession
redirect_uri: https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/auth-user-ephem
state: {"token":"(token)","endpoint":"(endpoint)","scopes":["openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]}
hd: (domain)
prompt: consent
client_id: (client_id)
scope: openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

My question: are there configurations on the auth to allow for authenticating?

Comment: Hi OP, can you share a sanitized version of the code you are running on Colab? This is to properly replicate your use case.

Comment: Sure. But it really stops running on authenticate_user()!

I can reproduce the error messages.

Answer (score 5):

I've encountered this problem too. It seems that Google have changed the authentication procedure so that you (or your organisation) have to add colaboratory to the list of apps with permission to access your account.

However, there's also a way to revert to the old authentication behaviour which works without any special permissions:

```
import os
os.environ['USE_AUTH_EPHEM'] = '0'

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/main/google/colab/auth.py#L224) of the `authenticate_user()` function, you can see that it reads the `USE_AUTH_EPHEM` environment variable to decide whether to use the old or new authentication flow.

Update:

An alternative (and possibly more future-proof) way to authenticate is by running the following line in Colab.

```
!gcloud auth login --no-browser --update-adc
```

This requires you to have the [Google Cloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) installed on your local machine, then just follow the instructions. If all goes well you'll be able to access BigQuery from within Colab without needing to call `auth.authenticate_user()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below alternative approach wherein you will upload your *json key file* (for authentication) in **Google Drive**, then **mount** it to **Google Colab** and then explicitly use it in your python code to authenticate your BigQuery API request.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.colab import drive
import json
# Construct a BigQuery client object.

drive.mount('/content/drive/') # Mount to google drive

# Define full path from Google Drive.
# This example, the json key file is in /MyDrive/keys/
key_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/keys/your-json-file.json' 

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)

query = """
    SELECT name, SUM(number) as total_people
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
    WHERE state = 'TX'
    GROUP BY name, state
    ORDER BY total_people DESC
    LIMIT 20
"""

query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request.

print("The query data:")
for row in query_job:
    # Row values can be accessed by field name or index.
    print("name={}, count={}".format(row[0], row["total_people"]))
```

Below is the result of my above sample code when executed in Google Colab:
[image]